# Why JSONproblem gets me : JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: java, json

Im using google maps api to get gps coordinate from google maps api.
im using almost similar code to my teacher code, for using JSON from api.
he his using api from darksky and im from google maps.

my code:

```
package com.company;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

public class MyCoorGiver {

public final String API_URL = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=";
private String cityName;

private final String apiKey = "&key=";
private String fullUrl;
private String rawData;
JSONObject jsonObject;

private double lat;
private double lng;

public String getFullUrl() {
    return fullUrl;
}

public MyCoorGiver(String cityName) {
    this.cityName = cityName;
    this.fullUrl = this.API_URL + cityName + this.apiKey;
}

private JSONObject readFromJsonUrl() throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(this.fullUrl).openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String jsonText = readAll(br);
    jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonText);
    return jsonObject;
}

    public String readAll(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        int cp;
        while((cp = br.read()) != -1){
            sb.append(cp);
        }
        rawData = sb.toString();
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public String getRaw(){
        return rawData;
    }

    private double getLat() throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject myData = readFromJsonUrl();
        JSONObject location = myData.getJSONObject("location");
        double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
        return lat;
    }

    private double getLng() throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject myData = readFromJsonUrl();
        JSONObject location = myData.getJSONObject("location");
        double lng = location.getDouble("lng");
        return lng;
    }


    public String makeCoorString() throws IOException, JSONException {
        lat = getLat();
        lng = getLng();
        String coor = lat + "," + lng;
        System.out.println(coor);
        return coor;
    }
```

}

the json url: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=RoshHaayin&key=ENTER_YOUR_API_KEY

the json :  (i dont know why it prints it like that but it look okay on my computer)

```
{
results: [
{
address_components: [
{
long_name: "ראש העין",
short_name: "ראש העין",
types: [
"locality",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "פתח תקווה",
short_name: "פתח תקווה",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_2",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "מחוז המרכז",
short_name: "מחוז המרכז",
types: [
"administrative_area_level_1",
"political"
]
},
{
long_name: "ישראל",
short_name: "IL",
types: [
"country",
"political"
]
}
],
formatted_address: "ראש העין, ישראל",
geometry: {
bounds: {
northeast: {
lat: 32.117834,
lng: 34.9994091
},
southwest: {
lat: 32.051418,
lng: 34.932534
}
},
location: {
lat: 32.095838,
lng: 34.952177
},
location_type: "APPROXIMATE",
viewport: {
northeast: {
lat: 32.117834,
lng: 34.9994091
},
southwest: {
lat: 32.051418,
lng: 34.932534
}
}
},
place_id: "ChIJTbFX6ioxHRURHn9WS3zh798",
types: [
"locality",
"political"
]
}
],
status: "OK"
}
```

Comment: You have to wrap all your keys in quotes `"`. Also, try this site: https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: i dont know how to do that because the url is formatted according to the city the user gives. and this is the url i get.. from the constructor

Comment: Requesting the data twice (`getLat()` and `getLng()` both call `readFromJsonUrl()`) in rapid succession is not a good practice in general, and it may even cause the problem if the second request triggers some DoS-protection scheme providing a non-JSON error message.

Comment: @tevemadar so i should do synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPD2：** `[` means an array and `{` means an object in the syntax of JSON. Have a try.

```
private double getLat() throws IOException, JSONException {
        JSONObject myData = readFromJsonUrl();
        JSONArray results = myData.getJSONArray("results");
        JSONObject geometry = results.getJSONObject(0).getJSONObject("geometry");
        JSONObject location = geometry.getJSONObject("location");
        double lat = location.getDouble("lat");
        return lat;
    }
```

**UPD：** You should use `readLine()` method instead of `read()`, try to change your code as below snippet.

```
public String readAll(BufferedReader br) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String cp;
        while ((cp = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(cp);
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
```

You can print `jsonText` in console to see if it is correct with JSON syntax. Perhaps you can try with this code.

```
private JSONObject readFromJsonUrl() throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL(this.fullUrl).openStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8")));
    String jsonText = readAll(br);
    //jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonText);
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JSONObject jsonObject = objectMapper.readValue(jsonText, JSONObject.class);
    return jsonObject;
}
```

Comment: i printed the jsonText it gives me a long number that starts with 123. i also tried your code and it gives me this:    org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException: Can not construct instance of org.json.JSONObject, problem: no suitable creator method found to deserialize from JSON integer number
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@2df32bf7; line: 1, column: 1]

Comment: so it must be something wrong in your code. You can not parse a JSONObject with wrong jsontext.

Comment: You get a long number because method `read()` returns an `int` result which is an Unicode. You can also convert Unicode to a char, and you would get a correct result. Changing the code as `sb.append((char)cp);`

Comment: the changing to a string in the readAll method. workrd but now i get :  JSONObject["location"] not found. i can see in the jsn there is a location key. help

Comment: You should operate the JSON Node one by one.

Comment: thank you very much its working finally :)